# Use ctime only for weekdays

Tags: linux, find, rm, xargs

I have a script to delete all folders created before past 2 days. 
Now, on Monday, it deletes just every folder from last week, which I do not want.

Is there an option to consider only weekdays for this command ? The whole script runs every day. I am using this:

```
find /my-folder/sub-folder/ -type d -ctime +1 | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: I would recommend running stat on the resulting list of results from find, extracting the modified time and then running date -d <date> +a checking for instances not Sat or Sun.

Comment: ctime IS NOT creation time

Answer (score 7):

You could do:

```
find /my-folder/sub-folder/ -type d -ctime "+$((
  1 + 2 * ($(date +%u) <= 2) ))" -prune -exec echo rm -rf {} +
```

That is, add 2 days if the current day is either 1 (Monday) or 2 (Tuesday) (assuming you're only running that script on week days).

I've added a `-prune` as it doesn't make sense to descend into directories that you are removing and replaced `xargs` which would fail for file names that contain blanks or backslashes or quotes with the standard `-exec ... {} +` alternative.

Note that the `ctime` of a directory  is not updated when a file within it is modified or when files are added or removed to/from sub-directories.

Comment: Asking will running this `find /dir/path -type d -ctime -6`in a cron job every Friday help?

Comment: `ctime` is not creation time.